# How to select a box with jQuery but not select the form inside the box?

Tags: html, jquery, select, click

I have a code where I want the page to close when the box is clicked with the "box-search" class
But even though I said don't consider the form and the elements inside the form, the form will be closed when the form and input are clicked.

```js
$(".box-search *").not('form, form *').click(function() {
  $(".box-search").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-search">
  <div class="container" style="font-size: 40px; color: red;">
    <button type="submit" class="close-box-search">Close</button>
    <form method="get" action="">
      <input type="text">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but if you want to click on something, and have the click influence only that (and not the parents), try `$(<your_selector>).click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation})`. If this is not what you need, please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: My question is exactly the opposite of what you said
I want it to be applied to the parent
But do not apply to the child

Comment: Apply to "box-search"
But do not apply on the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question
To select the parent, but not apply to the child
We use the following code

```
$(".box-search").click(function (e) { 
    if( $(e.target).hasClass("box-search") || $(e.target).hasClass("container") || $(e.target).hasClass("close-box-search") ){ 
        hideBoxSearch()
    }
});
```